# Join an array with an object in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I having an array

```
let dd =[0: {name:'clarie', dob:15/12/1990}]
```

and an object

```
let info ={state:'washigton',zip:'54665'}
```

I want to merge this 2 into like,

```
  let y = {name:'clarie', dob:15/12/1990,state:'washigton',zip:'54665'}
```

I used spread opertor,concat, but error occurs.

```
let y= [..dd[0], ..info]  like  this
```

How to join these two?

Comment: `let dd =[0: {name:'clarie', dob:15/12/1990}]` is not an valid array, please update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let y= {...(dd[0]), ...info}
```

You want to create a new object, not an array.

Comment: I am not saying  I want to create an new array

Comment: "let y= [..dd[0], ..info]  like  this" this would be something to create an array :)

Comment: oo yaa I typed wrong.. Sorry

Comment: No problems :) So, is your issue solved? Or does is still not work ? If it's solved, you should select a good answer to close the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Your current code spreads `info` object with `dd` array. You can't spread object properties onto an array. You should spread it as an object, as :

```
     const y = { ...info, ...dd[0] }
```

Also, the array initialization is wrong in the question,  `dob` should be string. Updated code:

```
  const dd = [{ name: "clarie", dob: "15/12/1990" }];
  const info = { state: "washigton", zip: "54665" };
  const y = { ...info, ...dd[0] }
```

[View demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-meitner-kbt5mu?file=/src/App.js)